# The usage of "also": could someone please give an example to illustrate where is the location "after the verb to be when it is a full verb"?

Tags: grammar

This video (https://youtu.be/38-K2rPu8fc?t=79) is talking about the usage of "also"

> In addition 'also' can be used in the normal mid position of adverbs. What is that?
>   It is between the subject and the predicate, or after the modal verb,
>   or after the first auxiliary verb, or after the verb to be when it is a full verb.

There are 4 locations where the "also" could be put.

1. location_1: between the subject and the predicate
2. location_2: after the modal verb
3. location_3: after the first auxiliary verb
4. location_4: after the verb to be when it is a full verb

she gives these examples

> She works very hard, but she also goes to the gym every week.

which applys location_1

> I've been working in a garden this week and I've also been reading a lot.

which applys location_3

I am aware what first 3 locations mean, the question is location_4, what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb "to be" (ie: am, is, are, was, were) can be an auxiliary verb (in "I am eating lunch") or the main verb (in "I am happy").

The word "also" can go after the verb in the latter case:

> He is big. He is also happy. He's also a bear.

Comment: In "I am eating lunch", "am" is the verb "to be", "am eating" is the full verb, right?

Comment: yes,  that is a present continuous verb