# The usage of "also": is it idiomatic put "also" at the end of a sentence in writing?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, idiomatic-language

This video (https://youtu.be/38-K2rPu8fc?t=167) is talking about the usage of "also" and gives this example

> She wrote three emails to him but he didn't answer, he ignored her calls as well.

And then the speaker substituted "also" for "as well", and said

> "He ignored her calls also." It sounds weird but it's possible.

That does sound weird for speaking, the question is for writing.

Is it idiomatic put also at the end of a sentence in writing?

Note: My another post ([The usage of "also": could someone please give an example to illustrate where is the location "after the verb to be when it is a full verb"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/238116/95044)) is relevant though, they are talking about different questions. This one is focused on the location of the end of a sentence.