# Is it a idiomatic style to use present continuous tense and simple present tense in the same one sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I asked a question ([The usage of "also": Is it idiomatic put also at the end of a sentence in writing?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/238121/95044)) just now, where I said

> This video is *talking* about the usage of "also" and *gives* this example ...

I used present continuous tense and simple present tense there, is this a idiomatic style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combination of tenses is fine and perfectly idiomatic.

Whether videos **talk** is moot although the meaning is clear. If you wanted to be more particular, you could refer to the **video presenter**. In informal English, however, there's no problem.