# When refer to where to put adverb, which one is more idiomatic, location or position?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

This post ([The usage of "also": could someone please give an example to illustrate where is the location "after the verb to be when it is a full verb"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/238116/95044)) is talking about some sentence structure.

1. location_1: between the subject and the predicate
2. location_2: after the modal verb
3. location_3: after the first auxiliary verb
4. location_4: after the verb to be when it is a full verb

When refer to where to put "also", which one is more idiomatic, location or position?